# What is the syntax for the HTML5 media attribute value with an expression?

Tags: html

I was wondering what is the syntax for the media attributes value with an expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The standard for HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#the-source-element) says:

> The media attribute gives the intended
>   media type of the media resource, to
>   help the user agent determine if this
>   media resource is useful to the user
>   before fetching it. Its value must be
>   a valid [media query](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-mediaqueries/).

Follow that second link for the full syntax details.

Comment: can you explain this expression for me?
 `: '(' S* media_feature S* [ ':' S* expr ]? ')' S*` what does the S* mean for instance.

Comment: that's a formal grammar definition. if you don't understand it, you'll need to read the [css2 grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) specification. That's a pretty complex topic. Just look at all the examples on the page to understand how the attributes work. If you want to really understand the formal syntax, you'll need to study quite a bit. [The Lex/YACC Primer](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO.html) has a good rundown with examples.

Comment: thanks for the help if I cant understand it I'll post it as a question later on.